# Как учесть размер скролбара или убрать вносимый им эффект?

Tags: html, css

Имеем такую модель. Основная часть сайта в `.container`, ограничена минимальной и максимальной шириной (для "резиновости"). Нужно создать зафиксированный блок в нижней части окна браузера на всю доступную ширину, но контент внутри него должен быть ограничен по ширине так же как же как контейнер. Все бы ничего, но в расчеты вмешивается размер вертикального скролла. В принципе я могу решить этот вопрос просто задав для `.bar {overflow-y: scroll}`. Но это костыль и мне не хотелось бы его применять. Как сделать красиво?

ps: Html можно менять то же если что.

**Код:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 120vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(100vh - 4em);
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 100vw;
}

.bar .container {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, как понять вот это  width: 100%;  max-width: 400px;? На кой задавать ширину 100% а потом ее ограничивать, для каких целей?

Comment: И вообще непонятная конструкция... И вопрос непонятен...

Comment: @Air Потому что не требуется делать бесконечно широкий сайт. Нужно чтобы при вьюпортах выше 400px по центру была колонка с контентом, а справа и слева от нее пустое пространство. Впрочем это не относится к сути вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте,исправьте в стилях для bar width:100%.Как вы верно заметили,проблемы из-за ползунка,но Вы ведь используете единицу измерения vw - % от ширины окна(ползунок тоже имеет свою ширину).Можете у класса container уменьшить высоту и посмотреть.

Comment: Вы правы. Какое-то затмение накатило просто.